# how to get the qna response inside QnAMakerDialogbase: QnAMakerDialog

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am using botframework v4 and I want to create a rich card from QNAmaker responses. I was checking the QnAMakerDialog interface but couldn't find any useful method for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QnAMakerDialog class has a privet method DisplayQnAResultAsync which responsible for getting the QnA response and display it. there is currently a PR to change this method to "protected" so we can override it. so currently I have to write my own QnAMakerDialog class until the PR is released